# Integral of nonnegative function on plane domain gives a negative result, what is wrong?

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-verification

Given an area $D: x \ge y, 0 \le x \le 1, y \ge 0$.
$$ f(x,y)= 
 \begin{cases} 2, & (x,y) \in D,\\
 0, & \text {others}\end{cases} $$

For this area $D_1: x+y \le 1, 0 \le y \le x$, I'm calculating:
$$ \iint_{x+y\le 1} f(x, y) dx dy= \iint_{D1} 2dxdy =   
\int_0^\frac12 2dx \int_x^xdy+ \int_\frac12^12dx \int_x^{1-x} dy $$
$$= 0 + \int_\frac12^12dx \left[y|_x^{1-x} \right] = \int_\frac12^12 (1- 2x) dx = 2(x-x^2)|_\frac12^1 = 0 - 2(\frac12 - \frac14) = - \frac12 $$

But the correct answer is $\frac12$. I don't know what is wrong in my steps. Please help me.

Comment: $\iint_{x+y\le 1} f(x, y) dx dy= \iint_{D1} 2dxdy =   
\int_0^\frac12 2dx \int_0^xdy+ \int_\frac12^12dx \int_0^{1-x} dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral set up is wrong:

$$I =  \iint_{x+y\le 1} f(x, y) dx dy= \iint_{D1} 2dxdy =   
\int_0^\frac12 \int_0^x2dydx+ \int_\frac12^1  \int_0^{1-x} 2dydx $$

If you evaluate this you get $\frac12$

$$ 2\left[\frac{x^2}{2}|_0^\frac12 +(x-\frac{x^2}{2})|_\frac12^1\right]$$